# ListView not working on MapView window?

Tags: android, google-maps, listview, android-listview

I am using a MapFragment to display a Google map. On a Google map point I am displaying the custom window with a ListView. I have added a list of view items in ListView but the scrolling is not working on ListView in this window.

Please help me get scrolling work on my ListView.

Here is my code:

mapview.xml

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

when click point on the mapview we display the listview.xml

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/mappostlistviewID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:dividerHeight="3dp" >
    </ListView>
```

In the list, we have added the same item.

Comment: please explain "scrolling is not working " ?

Comment: You can look at this https://github.com/dlukashev/AndroidSlidingUpPanel-foursquare-map-demo

Comment: @DavidJhons yes scrolling is not working on that window. if i am touch the window the mapview is moving. but list view is not scroll.

Comment: post your layout xml please

Comment: @David see i have post the xml files

Answer (score 0):

There may be reasons for your issue .

1. According to your listView properties, you have define the height as  wrap_content. So it will not scroll , it will define the height according to the amount of adding elements.

In order to fix that, define some fixed height for the listview.

2. Also make sure you have enough element where total height is bigger than the definded height of the listview.

Try with large number of elements.